# JS Pop-Out Follow Modal Dialog (Facebook or Twitter)?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, facebook, twitter

Are there any tools I can use so that if someone clicks on a facebook or twitter link on my webpage, a panel could popup where they could do that without leaving my site.

Do any plugins exist for this?

I've seen the addthis share controls used but they seem to just be for sharing, not following....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Facebook Like-button uses an iFrame, for example.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a similar thing for 'Follow' though ?